# Session only registering when set directly from the login page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

```
<?php
session_start();


   if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
       require_once('logged.html');
   } else {
       require_once('notlogged.html');
   }
?>
```

This code works fine when I login directly from the login page, but when I start from the homepage, then a href to the login page, login, it still shows the notlogged.html.
But when I start from the login page, I can login and get to logged.html, go to the signout page and destroy my session, which lands me to the notlogged.html, then login again to the logged.html.

So basically, it works perfectly when I enter from login.php, but not when I enter from index.php. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: The question is not much clear. Where the Login form is ? Is it in a Pop Up Modal Or where ?

Comment: @JohnDoe its in login.php, which is a subdomain or something example.com/login.php

Answer (score 0):

question isn't clear, 1st of all check whether session created while login from any page, its simple after creating session variable, make alert using JS

alert("$_SESSION['login_user']");